# Как реализовать performClick()?

Tags: java, android

Считывает только постоянное движение пальцем по экрану (ACTION_MOVE) и если тыкнуть пальцем по экрану и зажать, то это сочтёт как за 1 тык (ACTION_DOWN), а мне нужно, чтобы этот тык был постоянным, как зажатие, чтобы постоянно событие это происходило, а не 1 раз, ну, как при ACTION_MOVE, но чтобы палец на одном месте был.

Вот код:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Game game = new Game();
    if (!game.PAUSE) {
        switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                gameManager.onTouchEvent((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
                invalidate();
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                performClick();
                gameManager.onTouchEvent((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
                invalidate();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean performClick() {
    super.performClick();
    return true;
}
```

Помогите, как реализовать это? Год назад и без performClick() всё работало как надо, а сейчас вдруг метод onTouchEvent() попросил этот performClick(), я его добавил, но что сделать, чтобы он заработал, я не понимаю.

Comment: ну есть ещё ACTION_UP. а там уже в логике приложения смотреть надо как лучше сделать. хоть каждые X милисекунд таймер кинуть и отменить на подъёме пальца. Кстати, а мультитач предполагается в приложении?

Comment: Мультитач нет.
Я пробовал сделать ещё кейс с ACTION_UP и туда performClick() закинул, но изменений не дало. Можно пример какой-нибудь с таймером?

Comment: под рукой студии нету, как-то так (псевдокод): `CountDownTiemr timer; <....>  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: timer = new CountDownTiemr (100,10000){ public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         gameManager.onTouchEvent((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
     } <...> case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: timer.cancel();`

Comment: Попробовал с таймером, почему-то вообще на ACTION_DOWN ничего не происходит теперь)